# nginx doesn't honor subfolder error_page directives

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make my very simple nginx that is serving static files to fallback or otherwise show an error page if it's a 404 or 50x error like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name frontend;
  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

  error_page 404 = @fallback404;
  location @fallback404 {
    index index.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/404-error;
    internal;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 @fallback5xx;
  location @fallback5xx {
    index index.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/5xx-errors;
  }

  location /testing500 {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/does/not/exist;
  }

  location / {
    autoindex off;
    index index.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Even `/testing/500` returns plan nginx's 404 page:

[image]

I also been trying to declare error_page directives as location to their respective subfolders where the actual index.html with an error is residing, in my case: `/404-error/index.html` and `/5xx-errors/index.html` without using the `@fallbackXXX` definition, the effect was the same.

What did I miss? is nginx not respecting error pages being in a subfolder or something?

Comment: I don't think `location @fallback404` actually does much. You should add `try_files /index.html =404;` to that location to force Nginx to find your file.

Comment: This qualifies as an answer, it worked, want to post it. so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `try_files` statement to the `location @fallback404` block to select the correct URI to be returned.

For example:

```
error_page 404 = @fallback404;
location @fallback404 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/404-error;
    try_files /index.html =404;
    internal;
}
```

---

However, a simpler solution would be to specify the URI in the `error_page` statement itself.

For example:

```
error_page 404 /404-error/index.html;
location = /404-error/index.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}
```